# MATLAB error of no output from a factorial function

Tags: matlab, windows-7

This is a MATLAB code on win 7.

```
function c = myFactorial(n)
if n < 0
   c = "n should be positive !";
else
   if n == 0
       c = 1;
   else 
       c = n*myFactorial(n-1);
   end
end
d = myFactorial(3);
printf("d is %d", d);
```

But, I got error:

```
 Error: Function definition unexpected!
```

The function must be defined in another .m file ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: I am afraid the string in Matlab is indicated with `'` not `"`. Besides if you just want to print to command prompt you can just write `d` in a new line at the end of your function (instead of `printf("d is %d", d);` which is totally wrong in Matlab). and Yes the function should be in a separate `mfile` with the same name of the function (`myFactorial.m` in your case).

Comment: Deleted my post after I realized ans. is already there in the comment :).

Comment: I think you don't need another file, just try to  place the function part in the buttom of the code.

Comment: BTW there is no `printf` in MATLAB. There's `fprintf`.